# /Library/Spelling not found

Tags: mac, dictionary, library, spelling

I am a new Mac user trying to set up spelling checker for MS Office. I have downloaded the .dic & .aff files that I have to add to my /Library/Spelling folder. However, I have not managed to find this folder. I have looked it up in my Finder and also used Terminals to make files shown, in case it is a hidden one (even though that would not make much sense..), I still havent found the Spelling file.

Comment: MS Word does NOT use anything from OS X for spellcheck, it has it own proofing tools.  Installing .dic  & .aff files in Spelling will not accomplish anything for that app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not `/Library/Spelling/` it's `~/Library/Spelling/` & yes, it is hidden by default, as is the entire `~/Library`.

~/ is the standard abbreviation for `Macintosh HD/Users/your name/`[your Home folder] the equivalent of Windows' environmental variables like `%appdata%` etc.

To see it temporarily hold down the Option key and select Library from the Go menu in Finder.

To make it permanently visible, Show View Options for your Home folder. Check the box to show the Library.

Comment: oh ok, silly me, my bad!! :) thanks a lot for the reply!

Answer (score 0):

on Catalina OS Library/spelling, exist only documents with .dat extension[image]

Comment: But your graphic clearly shows .dic and .aff files for a 3rd party Slovenian spellchecker!